# Is it possible to use biodiesel in a BMW 335d if I remove the DPF and remap the ECU?

Tags: fuel-system, bmw, exhaust, diesel

The new (2009-current) BMW 335d sells in the U.S. with a DPF to reduce emissions, but which prevents the use of biodiesel.  I've read about people removing the DPF and re-mapping their ECU to get better performance out of the engine.  I'm wondering if doing this would allow the use of biodiesel without mechanical problems.

I am *not* asking about the implications on factory warranty.

I am *not* asking why using biodiesel is a bad idea (or a good one).

Answer (score 5):

Yes but as of present there are no US based tuners that provide a DPF delete kit or engine tuning (reprogramming) to allow the safe removal of this device.  They exist overseas in the UK and Europe but I would hold off until someone in the US provides a product specific to the US car.  Also the US spec 335d uses a DEF (diesel exhaust fluid, adblue, urea injection whatever you want to call it) system that will likely have to be disabled and removed through a reprogramming and since to my knowledge ONLY the US-spec cars use DEF the coding does not yet exist.  Check out this thread...

http://www.e90post.com/forums/showthread.php?p=9597657#post9597657